# Is there an elegant way to remap group values into an incremental series in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an elegant way to reassign group values to increasing ones?

I have a table which has is already in order:

```
X = pandas.DataFrame([['a',2],['b',4],['ba',4],['c',8]],columns=['value','group'])

X
Out[18]: 
  value  group
0     a      2
1     b      4
2    ba      4
3     c      8
```

But I would like to remap group values to that they would increase one by one. The end result would look like:

```
  value  group
0     a      1
1     b      2
2    ba      2
3     c      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `category` or `factorize`

```
X.group.astype('category').cat.codes+1 # pd.factorize(X.group)[0]+1

Out[105]: 
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
dtype: int8
```